# How to capture USB data on the oscilloscope?

Tags: usb, oscilloscope

Using 2 channel oscilloscope (BK precision 2542B), channel 1 trigger on the triggered signal, channel 2 is on the Data+ of the USB port.

After sending the triggered signal to the bar code scanner, I can be able to read the data back and display it on the laptop terminal. However, I can't capture its data on channel 2 of the scope. I can only see the trigger signal on channel 1.

The scope GND leads were connected to GND on the board. What did I do wrong?  I just wanted to measure the timing how fast I get the data after sending the trigger signal.

Comment: Your oscilloscope is only 100 MHz. USB-2 data is almost three times faster than that, and USB-3 is faster still. Could that be your problem?

Comment: Unless you are building USB gear at electrical level (and possibly even then) you are probably better off using USB packet capture on the host, or even debugging at the level where your application interacts with the USB hardware drivers.

Comment: The actual problem with the scope may well be that you are looking in the wrong place in time, not that it can't keep up with the USB rate actually in use.  Try triggering on the USB data lines instead to see if you see anything at all.  Realize that the USB operation resulting from your action will probably occur at a *variable* delay after it corresponding to the next time when the host *polls* the device, so if you want to trigger on an event look for at least a millisecond thereafter for traffic.

Comment: Yes, Chris is right: all USB transfers are initiated by the host, so the host polls frequently and the device sends along the data when asked for. The time of the actual barcode scan is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

To measure a digital signal the Nyquist-Shannon theorem says you need a scope with a sampling rate at the very least twice as fast as the frequency of the signal you are sampling. An USB 2.0 bus is capable of 480Mbit/s, which means you would need a scope capable of AT LEAST 1GS/s (a billion samples per second) to be able to resolve individual bits. You have the wrong equipment for the job.

Comment: The mentioned bar code scanner is unlikely to be running at USB2 speed (there would be little point), but rather at 12 mbs or 1.5 mbs, which should be within the capability of the mentioned scope, though a scope is not going to be the easiest way of *interpreting* it.

Comment: Well, the data is NZRI encoded over a differential pair, so you would need to integrate D+ and D- into a differential amplifier and decode the NZRI stream, or capture both D+ and D- and run them through a suitable protocol analyzer.

Comment: Also note that while USB 2.0 is faster than 1.0 in throughput, the actual bit time is constant across all versions of the protocol. However due to bit stuffing and NZRI encoding I will concede the slower connections can probably be read accurately some of the time with a 100MHz scope.

Comment: No, you are quite mistaken in your claim about "bit time".  Consider you can bit-bang 1.5 mbps USB *in software* on a 12 MHz MCU, vs how many transitions the higher rate versions would have to fit into the time of each of those slow rate bits.  The only place what you are imaging would be true would be between a USB2 host and hub, when the data itself is intended for a slower speed client of that hub - there you would have the short message transmitted quickly on the master bus, then repeated slowly to the peripheral on the secondary bus one.

Comment: The fact that you can bit bang it is a consequence of the NZRI encoding and bit stuffing. A software stack like V-USB for AVRs for example can bit bang USB at very low speeds by forcing their own timing through the differential encoding. They behave completely differently than a normal USB device would. So if your goal is to capture traffic from a bit banged device, you might be ok, but for a device using a hardware stack, even a low-speed one, I don't think 100MHz will be accurate enough.

Comment: If that is what you believe you are grossly mistaken... **as made obvious by the fact that the software devices can receive, not just transmit**.  If an MCU can operationally receive while sampling at no more than its 12 MHz clock rate, a 100 MHz *bandwidth* scope (which is really sampling several times faster than that, probably 1 GSPS or 500 MSPS in dual trace mode) can capture the data *if used correctly*.  Making sense of it is another matter.